# VB.net - convert PDF bytes to string

Tags: vb.net

I have the below response in a `json` format, from an API request of printing something and it contains PDF bytes:

```
%PDF-1.7 %??5 0 obj <</Filter/FlateDecode/Alternate/DeviceRGB/Length 2592/N 3>>stream x???wTS???7??" %? ?H?. !  BB?+?#??4E?A??Q,??O?ADG??F?y??g}k????.
```

The idea is that I need to convert that into a string using VB and I wasn't able to find something that would help me on the web.

Can someone give me a hint on how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Base64 methods to convert byte[] to String.

```
Dim b As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(pdfByte)
Dim finalString As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b)
```

btw. I don't know how the json response will be created but there is something wrong. You can not get anything useful out of `x???wTS???7??" %? ?H?. !  BB?+?#??4E?A??Q,
??O?ADG??F?y??g}k????.`

There is a problem on the other site. It should convert the bytes to a Base64 String and then it will work.